# In Java, will multiple threads await() the same condition get unlocked at the same time later?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, if multiple threads await() the same conditionA, then another thread calls signalAll() on conditionA, will all the threads waiting for conditionA get unlocked at the same time?

For example, I have an add and a remove method of a queue:

```
public void add(E newValue) throws InterruptedException
{
    queueLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while (size == elements.length)
            spaceAvailableCondition.await();
        elements[tail] = newValue;
        tail++;
        size++;
        if (tail == elements.length)
            tail = 0;
        valueAvailableCondition.signalAll();
     }
     finally
     {
         queueLock.unlock();
     }
}

public E remove() throws InterruptedException
{
    queueLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while (size == 0)
            valueAvailableCondition.await();
        E r = (E) elements[head];
        head++;
        size--;
        if (head == elements.length)
            head = 0;
        spaceAvailableCondition.signalAll();
        return r;
    }
    finally
    {
        queueLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Suppose multiple threads keep calling add method on a shared queue. After a while, the queue is full. All those threads are stuck at `spaceAvailableCondition.awati()`. Then, I have this thread that calls the method remove, `signalAll()` the `spaceAvailableCondition`. Will all the threads that called add get unlocked and run the method, which will cause a corruption on that queue?

I ask this question because I think all the other 'adding threads' have implemented `queueLock.lock()`. Then all the thread have ownership of this lock.

Comment: Why don't you try it with a simple print?

Comment: @Bifz Because "give it a try" isn't a suitable approach to reasoning about concurrency.

Comment: If you put a print right after wait and call signal once, than you should see how many did wake up.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question right.

Although `await`ing threads will be woken up by `signalAll()`, but only one of them is able to re-acquire the lock (I assume is the `queueLock`) associated with the `spaceAvailableCondition` those thread are awaiting at.  Hence, only 1 "add" thread is going to execute the logic.

Comment: And the one which re-acquires the lock is the one with _hieghst priority._ right?

Comment: I cannot recall from my memory that thread priority has anything to do with the order of awake (hence able to acquire the lock).  I believe it is implementation-depedent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `spaceAvailableCondition` is a condition variable that was obtained from `queueLock`, then no, they won't wake up "at the same time".

You already know that you're not allowed to call `spaceAvailableCondition()` from a thread that doesn't have `queueLock` locked.  That's because, the `spaceAvailableCondition.await()` call does these things:

1. It releases `queueLock`.
2. It waits for another thread to signal the condition,
3. It re-acquires `queueLock`
4. It returns.

Only one thread can own the `queueLock` at a time, so when the condition is signalled, only one thread will be able immediately return from the `await()` call.  The next thread will not be able to acquire the lock and return from `await()` until the first one releases the lock, and so on.